# Hadoop error on executing job

Tags: java, exception, hadoop

I tried to run an example and get the following output:

```
12/06/30 12:27:39 INFO jvm.JvmMetrics: Initializing JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId=
12/06/30 12:27:39 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 7
12/06/30 12:27:40 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_local_0001
12/06/30 12:27:40 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 7
12/06/30 12:27:40 INFO mapred.MapTask: io.sort.mb = 100
12/06/30 12:27:41 INFO mapred.MapTask: data buffer = 79691776/99614720
12/06/30 12:27:41 INFO mapred.MapTask: record buffer = 262144/327680
12/06/30 12:27:41 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
12/06/30 12:27:41 INFO mapred.MapTask: Starting flush of map output
12/06/30 12:27:41 WARN mapred.LocalJobRunner: job_local_0001
java.io.IOException: Expecting a line not the end of stream
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.DF.parseExecResult(DF.java:109)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:179)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:134)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.DF.getAvailable(DF.java:73)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator$AllocatorPerContext.getLocalPathForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:329)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator.getLocalPathForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:124)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapOutputFile.getSpillFileForWrite(MapOutputFile.java:107)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.sortAndSpill(MapTask.java:1221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.flush(MapTask.java:1129)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewOutputCollector.close(MapTask.java:549)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:623)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:305)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:177)
12/06/30 12:27:42 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job complete: job_local_0001
12/06/30 12:27:42 INFO mapred.JobClient: Counters: 0
```

Does anyone know why I get this error? Hadoop version is 0.20.2.

Comment: Does your system have the `df` shell command available to the hadoop user? if you run this command manually from a shell, what does the output look like. At the moment, the error is saying that the df command return either 0 lines, or a number of lines less that what was expected (say a single header line and no partition information)

Comment: I can run the command for the user with which I started hadoop.

Comment: If I run an example with "bin/hadoop jar hadoop-0.20.2-examples.jar wordcount /input /output" it works okay. But if I try to run from eclipse it gives me the above error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently you need to have the `df` command available on the machine on which you have eclipse too. In my case I had 2 ubuntu VMs (acting as master and slave) and was running eclipse with the hadoop plugin from windows. After installing cygwin and adding it to the path it doesn't give that error anymore.

Comment: I got it to work using a stub/fake shell script called `df` in my path that just echoed output similar to what the real `df` might produce. https://gist.github.com/meonkeys/5360891